# Is it possible to play Fable 3 through Wine?

Tags: 11.04, wine, games

Fable 3 for PC just came out this week, and I got the game but I am too lazy to reinstall windows, so I am just wondering if is possible to play Fable 3 through wine in Ubuntu?

by the way, My Ubuntu is 11.04 and Wine Version is 1.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. it works very well! i used the wizard selecting fable: the lost chapters but i select the setup.exe from the full extracted .iso of Fable III , playonlinux are very good!

Comment: I try the playonlinux method but it give me a error code

Comment: I was having with setup.exe, but then just for the sake of trying,I try changing the game.msi as executable and it did run the installer

Comment: I am trouble with running it, it keep having error with F3Secu.exe

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be certain it works is to try. On some computers it will, on other it might not work.

Have you tried [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)? Fable 3 was recently released for MS Windows not many days ago, so it might be too "fresh" for PlayOnLinux.

Comment: it seen to be not working, even with the newest version of wine